# Extract Words From Text That Have More Than 4 Charecters and Are A-Z

Tags: php

Hello I got this code from this this website and it works fine but want to be able to only show words with 4 charecters or more and A-Z no numbers. Any help would be very much appreciated thanks!

```
$myvalue = "no no2 yess";
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
echo $arr[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myvalue = "no no2 yess";
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
```

Explode is cutting your string by delimeter ( ' ' ), and putting content into and array ( $arr ).

```
echo $arr[0]; // outputs 'no'
echo $arr[1]; // outputs 'no2'
echo $arr[2]; // outputs 'yess'



foreach($arr as $value){ // loop throught each element

//test if element is longer or equal to 4 and have only a-z A-Z.

    if(strlen($value) >=4 & preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]{4,}$/', $value)){ 

//return the matching words
        echo $value;

    }
}
```

Here you can putt them again into the array like $newArray[] = $value instead of echo $value, and throw them out with loop anywhere.

Comment: Hey thanks it does work but where do I add the [0] value exactly. When I add it I get like three words squashed into 1.

Comment: @user happy to help :]